# How to hide all the next "fieldset" elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Within an HTML form I have many `fieldset` elements.

Every time a radio/checkbox/select input change, I want to see if there is a custom HTML5 attribute called "terminator." If the attribute exists and have a value == "Yes", I want to hide all of the `fieldset` following the current `fieldset`.

here is my HTML code "if needed"

```
<div class="panel panel-default " id="question_8">
    <div class="panel-heading">1:b) What is the closest store to you home?</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <fieldset class="survey-control-fieldset" id="wrapper_111">
            <div class="survey-control-title"> Select a store </div>
            <!-- Open New Row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_34">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_34" value="111:34"> Larson LLC </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_210">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_210" value="111:210"> Waelchi, Ryan and Wunsch </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_239">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_239" value="111:239"> McGlynn, Hamill and Shields </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
            </div>
            <!-- Row Closed -->
            <!-- Open New Row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_391">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_391" value="111:391"> Hessel, Blick and Schiller </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_423">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_423" value="111:423"> Beatty-Schaefer </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_596">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_596" value="111:596"> Paucek-Kunze </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
            </div>
            <!-- Row Closed -->
            <!-- Open New Row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_684">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_684" value="111:684"> Johns, Oberbrunner and Pfannerstill </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_688">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_688" value="111:688"> Johns, Hamill and Senger </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_859">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_859" value="111:859"> Romaguera, Hayes and Bradtke </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
            </div>
            <!-- Row Closed -->
            <!-- Open New Row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_860">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_860" value="111:860"> Goyette, Gerhold and Schulist </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_529">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_529" value="112:529" checked> None </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_530">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_530" value="112:530"> Don&#039;t Know/No Answer </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
            </div>
            <!-- Row Closed -->
            <!-- Open New Row -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_532">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_532" value="112:532"> Other </label>
                        <div class="control_111 hiddenGroup " id="group_112_532">
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <label for="control_113">Specify Other Store Name</label>
                                <input placeholder="" class="form-control" name="control_113" type="text" value="" id="control_113"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="item_531">
                            <input type="radio" name="control_111" id="item_531" value="112:531" data-terminator="Yes"> Refused </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
                <!-- Open New Cell -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> </div>
                <!-- Cell Closed -->
            </div>
            <!-- Row Closed -->
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default " id="question_9">
    <div class="panel-heading">1:c) Pick you favorit stores</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <fieldset class="survey-control-fieldset" id="wrapper_114">
            <div class="survey-control-title"> Stores </div>
            <select class="form-control" name="control_114[]" id="control_114" multiple>
                <option id="item_34" value="114:34">Larson LLC</option>
                <option id="item_210" value="114:210">Waelchi, Ryan and Wunsch</option>
                <option id="item_239" value="114:239">McGlynn, Hamill and Shields</option>
                <option id="item_391" value="114:391">Hessel, Blick and Schiller</option>
                <option id="item_423" value="114:423">Beatty-Schaefer</option>
                <option id="item_596" value="114:596">Paucek-Kunze</option>
                <option id="item_684" value="114:684">Johns, Oberbrunner and Pfannerstill</option>
                <option id="item_688" value="114:688">Johns, Hamill and Senger</option>
                <option id="item_859" value="114:859">Romaguera, Hayes and Bradtke</option>
                <option id="item_860" value="114:860">Goyette, Gerhold and Schulist</option>
                <option id="item_533" value="115:533" selected>115 Jay&#039;s Wireless</option>
                <option id="item_534" value="115:534" selected>115 Ajs Alterations</option>
                <option id="item_535" value="115:535">115 Check Box Signs</option>
                <option id="item_536" value="115:536">115 Jace&#039;s Super Center</option>
                <option id="item_537" value="116:537" selected>116 Jay&#039;s Wireless</option>
                <option id="item_538" value="116:538" selected>116 Ajs Alterations</option>
                <option id="item_539" value="116:539">116 Check Box Signs</option>
                <option id="item_540" value="116:540">116 Jace&#039;s Super Center</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
```

Here is what I have tried, the code below will print "Yes" or "No" to the console but it does not hide all the fieldset like I expect

```
$("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox'],select").change(function(e) {

        //Get the shared class name which has the same name at the "name" attribute of the radio control
        var isTerminator = $(this).data('terminator') || 'No';
        console.log(isTerminator);
        //Hide all groups that have the class equal to className
        if(isTerminator == 'Yes'){
            $( this ).nextAll('fieldset').hide().addClass('terminated');
        } else {
            $( this ).show().removeClass('terminated');
        }

    });
```

In the example above, if the element with the id = "item_531" is selected then the `fieldset` below id="wrapper_111" should hide.

How can I hide all the next fieldset `elements`?

Comment: Change `$( this ).nextAll('fieldset').hide().addClass('terminated');` to `$( this ).closest('fieldset').hide().addClass('terminated');`. [More info](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: no.... this: $(this).closest(".panel").nextAll().find("fieldset").hide().addClass('terminated');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.nextAll('fieldset')** looks for fieldsets directly after the current one in the DOM.  Because in your HTML your fieldsets are nested within some DIVs it doesn't find any more and returns a list of length 0.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but you could try find the parent divs (e.g. with class **panel**), then nextAll() to get other panels then with those panels find the fieldsets and hide them.  E.g.

```
$(this).parents(".panel").nextAll().find("fieldset").hide().addClass('terminated');
```

Otherwise you would need to change your HTML to make the fieldsets siblings in the DOM.  Another thing to consider, your class **terminated** could have css **display:none** and then adding and removing the class would mean you didn't need the .hide() and .show().

Comment: Thank you. what I am trying to do here is hide everything below. I guess I will have to hide the outter dive instead of the fieldset. How would I find that outter div and hide it?

Comment: What Quantumplate suggests will work fine. You should use .closest() instead of .parents() though..

Comment: @Repo what is the different between using parent and closest? they both worked

Comment: This is the code that is working and I am using      `if(isTerminator == 'Yes'){
            $(this).closest(".panel").nextAll().hide().addClass(className);
     } else {
            $(this).closest(".panel").nextAll().show().removeClass(className);
     }`

Comment: closest will give you the closest parent with the specified selector, parents will give you all parents with the specified selector. So if you are a 100 percent sure that only one parent will have the selector, then it will work fine. Closest is just more correct and it stops searching when it finds the closest parent, so it is faster as well..

Comment: @Repo thank you for the explanation that make since. How can I use the same logic to return the checkbox/radio/select input names? I tried this but it does not work             `$(this).closest(".panel").nextAll().find("input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox'],select").each(function(index, value){
                console.log( value.attr('name') );
            });`

Comment: At first glance it looks fine. But break your code into smaller pieces. var next = $(this).closest(".panel").nextAll(); and so on.. find out what is giving wrong data..